# Change Bones Axis Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, transform-orientation

I've had a problem the past couple days with animating my rig on the left side.. every time i upload a animation and rename all the bones to the rig on the right, the axis of the bones are wrong and it turns into a side scrolling animation. how can i change the bones axis/Orientation to the right rig?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a bone's axis by going into edit mode, selecting the bone, and pressing **Shift** + **N**. then you'll be able to change the transformation axis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcr2v.jpg